# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS screen is flickering on Dell Optiplex 9010 AIO system.

Tags: 14.04, dell, intel-graphics, flicker

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 on Dell Optiplex 9010, all in one system. As I boot from my bootable pendrive then screen flickers. I thought that problem may get solved after installation is complete but after installation screen is still flickering. Far left side has less flickering compared to far right side. Since Everything is working fine in Windows 7 so it seems issue of graphics drivers but I could not find any driver. I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but problem was not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working! Just installing latest 3.15 kernel (I tried 3.15 RC8 and 3.15.3 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/.

It works like a charm!

files to download 3.15.3 for 64-bit system:

- linux-headers-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_amd64.deb
- linux-headers-3.15.3-031503_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_all.deb
- linux-image-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_amd64.deb

files to download 3.15.3 for 32-bit system:

- linux-headers-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb
- linux-headers-3.15.3-031503_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb
- linux-image-3.15.3-031503-generic_3.15.3-031503.201407010040_i386.deb

Type in terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround... Use old version of kernels in 14.04.  Get three 3.9-11.xxx kernels from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9.11-saucy/

files to download for 64-bit system:

- linux-headers-3.9.11-030911-generic_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_amd64.deb
- linux-headers-3.9.11-030911_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_all.deb
- linux-image-3.9.11-030911-generic_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_amd64.deb

files to download for 32-bit system:

- linux-headers-3.9.11-030911-generic_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_i386.deb
- linux-headers-3.9.11-030911_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_all.deb
- linux-image-3.9.11-030911-generic_3.9.11-030911.201307202035_i386.deb

Type in terminal:

- sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu 13.04 and that worked fine but since that is not LTS therefore I will try these workarounds and then will set answer.

Comment: In my Dell inspiron, the screen flickers and the boot process from the live usb hangs. If I have to use the mentioned Kernel versions, how can I downgrade these kernels in the live usb image before installing it to the system?