# DELL Optiplex 9010 motion picture display problem on recent kernels

Tags: kernel, dell, video, scrolling

i have problems with display of motion picture (videos but also scrolling). It seems like often some parts of the screen are refreshed in different moments than the others. Most of the time the border between two parts is going horizontally for 1/3 of the screen then is falling down for another 1/3 and than again continues horizontally. Here is a link to a video (though I'm not sure if it caught the symptom or it's just me who sees it due to my system performance :) 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bGha8cPZl5XU9FzF2jjuypFlBxFUBpSS/view?usp=sharing
EDIT: Sorry, I think video fails, one time it appears, other time it doesn't. I'm leaving it, since I'm starting to doubt my own senses :)

Hardware:
I tried different monitors and cables (all on DisplayPort). I started with 2560x1080 monitor as you can guess by the video and first thought it's what causes the problem, but then switched to 1920x1080 monitor and it is the same. 
I use DELL Optiplex motherboard with integrated graphics, all I found on the board that seems like can be of significance is:
c        us
E93839   LA0601

DP/N
051FJ8
CN-051FJ8-72200
29G-02N8-A00

Software (everything is x64):
the problem appears on:
 - ubuntu mate 4.15-generic, 4.19-generic
 - regular ubuntu-18.04.3 (also 4.15-generic)

I found this thread:

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS screen is flickering on Dell Optiplex 9010 AIO system.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457658/ubuntu-14-04-lts-screen-is-flickering-on-dell-optiplex-9010-aio-system/1190123#1190123)

So, I tried ubuntu-14.10 as it has 3.16 kernel which is close to the 3.15 recommended in the thread. This solved the problem, but for some reasons system is super slow plus of course has security issues.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS outdate after 5 years, It's better to upgrade/install supported OS, such as 16.04 or 18.04 LTS.

Comment: As I wrote, I tried 18.04. I can still check 16.04 thou. Thx.